# Single UITableView with many-to-many obtained directly from Core Data

Tags: iphone, database, ipad, uitableview, core-data

Is it possible to have a single UITableView display records from two linked entities without converting NSFetchedResultsController results into arrays then nesting the arrays?

[image]

And have the UITableView results look like:

[image]

Any direction would be great and very well appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using [fetched properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-SW7)? :

> Fetched properties represent weak,
>   one-way relationships. In the
>   employees and departments domain, a
>   fetched property of a department might
>   be "recent hires" (employees do not
>   have an inverse to the recent hires
>   relationship). In general, fetched
>   properties are best suited to modeling
>   cross-store relationships, "loosely
>   coupled" relationships, and similar
>   transient groupings.